# Exporting a GIF for a large number of frames

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gif, adobe-after-effects

So I am working on my personal portfolio and am planning to include a GIF in the background. To give a brief idea, it basically shows the transition from a Mobile device to an I-pad and finally to a desktop screen. I created this animation in After-Effects and exported a PNG sequence. Since this is a 6-7 seconds animation, the number of individual PNGs is coming out to be somewhere around 650.
From What I know, I am opening this image sequence in Photoshop to create a GIF, but due to the large number of frames, it is only allowing me to create the GIF in 50% or less canvas size(the original is 1920X1080).I even tried bringing down the colors to 128.
Is there something wrong that I'm doing? And/or is there a better way to export GIFs like this?
If GIF is not a good option, should I use a video?

Thanks

Comment: you should use video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIF's grow very fast in File size because they are saved frame by frame unlike what video codec's do.

I'd use a video instead.

Combined with a autoplay feature (either trough a jquery vide plugin or trough a videoservice like vimeo or youtube which support loop and autoplay) you can get quite close to native gif functionality.

Comment: I am actually building my site on Squarespace. I want the gif to run in the hero image. Now Squarespace doesn't allow uploading a video :/
I guess i'll have to somehow reduce the size of the GIF itself. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Then your only option is to play around with loss and color reduction.